# How to generate robust verbatim bibliography data

Tags: biblatex, verbatim, shell-escape

I'm trying to generate a `.bib`-shaped "biblatex" database from a git change log. A typical(?) item looks like this:

```
@gitcommit{f1750d6,
 author = {Brent Longborough},
 date = {2013-12-15},
 title = {Complete name changes
Decomplicate top-level PROCs (&VERSION -> &CONFIG)
},
```

The `title` field, generated by this MWE, can contain *anything*, and I need to avoid any additional external commands (ie, sed, awk not allowed):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}
{\catcode`\%=12
\immediate\write18{
 git --no-pager log --reverse --pretty='format:@gitcommit{%h,%n 
 author = {%an},%n 
 date = {%ad},%n 
 title = {%B},%n
 commithash = {%H} 
 }' --date=short > \jobname.gll}
}
\end{document}
```

What should I try to generate in place of `title = {xxxx},`, and how can I inject any appropriate TeX commands into the `\write18`-generated `git` command line?

Comment: I'm fascinated by this and your other recent questions--are they motivated by your `gitinfo2` package?

Comment: @cmhughes Sort of. I had an email from a `gitinfo2` user asking me to add facilities for printing the changelog (don't remember who, and I can't find the email - sorry). My reaction was that is was a long way beyond my TeXnical capabilities. But then, a few days ago, I woke up at 3:30 am and shouted "it's a bibliography". So I'm sort of starting to write the `gitlog` package. (Best wait sitting down, but you can have a peek [here](https://github.com/Hightor/gitlog)).

Comment: @cmhughes Of course, it's still way beyond my TeXnical capacity, but "I get by with a lil' help from my friends".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`biblatex` has the aptly named field type `verbatim` that might fit the bill here. The [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) states (p. 14)

> Verbatim fields are processed in verbatim mode and may contain special
>   characters. Typical examples of verbatim fields are `file` and `doi`.

So all we need to do is make `title` a `verbatim` field via

```
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=verbatim]{
  title,
}
```

and we are good do go.

Of course there are a few things even `verbatim` fields can't stomach, so far I can only think of unmatched curly braces, but there might be more.
We don't need to worry about most other things, though. `%`s and `\`s are perfectly fine.

MWE (cave `filecontents`em: this will overwrite `gitlog.dbx`, `gitlog.bbx` and `\jobname.gll`)

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{gitlog.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{gitcommit}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{
  commithash,
}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=verbatim]{
  title,
}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[gitcommit]{
  title,
  author,
  date,
  commithash,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{gitlog.bbx}
\ProvidesFile{gitlog.bbx}[gitlog bibliography file 2015/11/17]

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printfield{entrykey}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{%
    \hspace\labelsep\ttfamily##1}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\newbibmacro*{begentry}{}
\newbibmacro*{finentry}{\finentry}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{gitcommit}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newblock%
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{commithash}
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\newbibmacro*{commithash}{%
    \printtext{%
       \printfield{commithash}%
}}

\endinput
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[%
    datamodel=gitlog,
    bibstyle=gitlog,
    sorting=none,
    date=iso8601,
    firstinits=true,
]{biblatex}


\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.gll}
@gitcommit{f1750d6,
 author = {Brent Longborough},
 date = {2013-12-15},
 title = {Complete name changes
Decomplicate top-level PROCs (&VERSION -> &CONFIG)
},
}
@gitcommit{9dce109,
 author = {Brent Longborough},
 date = {2015-11-15},
 title = {Initial commit &&&&&& %
},
 commithash = {9dce10970bb6be976ce59f76dd28e52abeb3b103} }
@gitcommit{f558cdd,
 author = {Brent Longborough},
 date = {2015-11-15},
 title = {First code to build pseudo-bibfile
},
 commithash = {f558cddc5a95acb1c081ead6f6e81cb9941941a0} }
@gitcommit{240f4c9,
 author = {Brent Longborough},
 date = {2015-11-15},
 title = {Added data model (not working) - now we step back a bit
},
 commithash = {240f4c9dbb22631f6098fbe45c409ef58cdddb09} }
@gitcommit{b4629f6,
 author = {Brent Longborough},
 date = {2015-11-16},
 title = {First working version full of restrictions
},
 commithash = {b4629f6bb7504b2d6e4a677294a761e1d1d5c659} }
@gitcommit{d651d24,
 author = {Brent Longborough},
 date = {2015-11-17},
 title = {Gradually improving things (especially understanding)
},
 commithash = {d651d249a3a14fd270a0f40e5d8124f6c552cc5b} }
@gitcommit{4c1dd2c,
 author = {Brent Longborough},
 date = {2015-11-17},
 title = {Making an MWE for TeX.SX},
 commithash = {4c1dd2c540ff8a2f2976d972d15071c1f54f9379},
verba = {4c1dd2c540ff8a2f2976d972d15071c1f54f9379} }
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.gll}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title={Change Log},type=gitcommit]
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Comment: I actually considered making `commithash` in the other question a `verbatim` field, but then I figured it only ever uses `a-z0-9` so there was no need. Note that usernames on githib might not always be names and could well contain weird characters, so there might be a need to `verbatim`-ise those as well, but then you lose all the nice name features Biber offers....

Comment: Wonderful - thanks! I *thought* I'd tried verbatim, but that was when I was still drowning in all the other problems. Give me a few minutes to retrofit, and I'll almost certainly accept this answer.

Comment: FFantastic! Now all I need to do is decent typography, github hyperlinks, etc, etc. (Sigh)

Comment: @Brent.Longborough For nice hyper-linking you can have a look at what `biblatex` does to the `doi` field (`\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
  \mkbibacro{DOI}\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}`)